# Styling VB.net Form With CSS & HTML?

Tags: html, css, vb.net

I am wondering if it is possible to style my VB.net application with CSS and HTML.  So far all I can do is apply a windows based theme.

Any help would be really appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try WPF

Comment: To elaborate, WPF allows you to create your interface in XAML, which is somewhat similar to HTML in terms of generating layouts and styling them. There's no CSS unfortunately, but such an engine wouldn't be too terribly difficult to write.

Answer (score 0):

WPF is much better if you want to style your app